# How to close Modal in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On button click i was trying to open a model (and modal opening too) and in a same modal it contain a button and on button click i was trying to open another  model (and second modal opening too), but when  second modal is opening i want first model to be closed. can it be possible?

Here is my sandbox demo https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-herschel-cyetn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
const Practice = () => {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
    const handleSubmit = event => {
        setModalShow(true);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onSubmit={handleSubmit} type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
            <Modals show={modalShow} onhide={() => setModalShow(false)} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

here is my modal part

```
const Modals = ({ show, onhide }) => {
    const [modalShowsec, setModalShowsec] = useState(false);

    const Validation = () => {
        setModalShowsec(true);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={onhide} size="sm" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">HELLO</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>Hi</p>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
            <button onClick={Validation}> Validate </button>
            <Modal show={modalShowsec} onHide={() => setModalShowsec(false)}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton />
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>Hi cool</p>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `onhide` inside `Validation` function. This will hide the first modal.

```
const Validation = () => { 
        setModalShowsec(true)
        onhide()
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Jagrati its closing both the model not the first one

Comment: so i  need to create another component and then call this inside parent component

Comment: Sorry, My mistake, Its not because of both the modals inside same component. Can you create a sandbox or demo for the issue.

Comment: Hi @Jagrati here is https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-herschel-cyetn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark Now if you click on submit a modal will open and if you again click on validate another modal will open but i want the first one should be closed

Comment: add `onhide()` inside `Validation` function  it is closing the first modal